# XNA - Getting a C# error

Tags: c#, xna

I'm making a game in XNA. Currently I'm working on collision detection. I can't resolve these 2 errors from my code:

```
// Non-static variables exist once for each instance of the class
Vector2 meteorPos;

// Static variables are shared between all instances of a class
public static Texture2D meteorTexture;
public Vector2 meteorPosPub { get { return meteorPos; } }

// Line that contains the errors
public static Rectangle boundingBox = new Rectangle((int)meteorPosPub.X, (int)meteorPosPub.Y, (int)meteorTexture.Width, (int)meteorTexture.Height);

public meteorGenerator(Vector2 pos)
{
    this.meteorPos = pos;
}
```

Here are the errors:

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'SpaceInvaders.meteorGenerator.meteorPosPub.get'
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'SpaceInvaders.meteorGenerator.meteorPosPub.get'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `boundingBox` field is static, but you're trying to access `meteorPosPub` which isn't static. The `boundingBox` needs to be non-static and that should fix that error.

Just remember non-static members can access static members, but static members cannot access non-static members. It makes sense if you think about it. The position of the meteor is going to be different for each instance of the object.

You'll also need to move the initialization of the field to the constructor since the value of meteorPosPub isn't known at the time you're trying to access it now:

```
...
public Rectangle boundingBox;

public meteorGenerator(Vector2 pos)
{
    this.meteorPos = pos;
    this.boundingBox = new Rectangle((int)meteorPosPub.X, (int)meteorPosPub.Y, meteorTexture.Width, meteorTexture.Height);
}
```

Comment: @Charlie Ahh you're right. I've updated my answer to fix that problem.

Comment: I thought of that too, but how do I access `boundingBox` from other classes then?

Comment: @Charlie The same way you'd access meteorPosPub. Something like `meteorGenerator meteor = new meteorGenerator(Vector2.Zero); meteor.boundingBox;` Best practice would be to make a boundingBox property, instead of a public field, but one challenge at a time.